# Getting the value from ($_GET["Value"])

Tags: php, sql, syntax, get, row

// PAGE ONE
     This is the index page, Here I am printing out rows from a list of
     movie´s with some basic info, title , year.
     I am also adding edit and delete links to the movies,
     these work by passing the row id's of that movie.

```
 $sql = "SELECT c.* , d.* FROM category c , movies d WHERE c.ID=d.ID";

 $result = $conn->query($sql);

 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<div class='floatbox collection'><table><tr><th>Titel</th><th>regissör</th><th>År</th><th>Genre</th><th>Ändra</th><th>Ta bort</th>";

 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo 
    "<tr><td>".$row["title"]."</td><td>".$row["director"]."</td><td>"

    .$row["year"]."</td><td>".$row["category"]."</td>

    <td><a href='edit.php?row=".$row["ID"]."'>justera</a></td>
        // delete link to send ID to next page
    <td><a href='delete.php?delete=".$row["ID"]."'>stryk</a></td>";
 }
 echo "</table></div>";
} else { 
    echo "0 results";
}



// PAGE TWO
Here I have my $row[ID] trough $_get by the link on the previous page,
I have checked the value by "dumping" so I know that the row ID is in that
variable: The thing is, How do I call that $ID in my sql statement?
I'm trying to delete by calling that ID on the table row.

// Variable with correct ID value
if(isset($_GET["ID"]))  

if($_GET["ID"]) = $ID; // This doesn't work, Do I need to convert 
the $get_ID to a variable with the ID that can be called in the statement? 
or is my syntax wrong?

// Delete join
$sql = "SELECT * FROM movies, category  
       INNER JOIN category ON movies.ID = category.ID
       DELETE WHERE movies.ID = '$ID'"; // No syntax works here
       // Any help appreciated.

// konfirmering
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Register struket <br>
     <a href='panel.php'>Gå tillbaka</a>";
} else {
    echo "Fel vid anslutning : " . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: `if($_GET["ID"]) = $ID;` what are trying to do here?

Comment: your second page is `delete.php` ?

Comment: Im trying to assign the forwarded value (the id) to a variable i can use in a sql query!  yes the second page is delete.php

Comment: please check my answer for that.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code your **delete.php** would be like this:

```
// Variable with correct ID value
if (isset($_GET["delete"])) {
    $ID = $_GET["delete"];

    // Delete join
    $sql = "DELETE FROM movies, category INNER JOIN category ON movies.ID = category.ID WHERE movies.ID = '$ID'";

    // konfirmering
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Register struket <br><a href='panel.php'>Gå tillbaka</a>";
    } else {
        echo "Fel vid anslutning : " . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: though i the join in the delete stmt doesnt work  at all, I read that delete statements cant take more thatn one "from" parameter and therefore the join does'nt work,  i made this instead : $sql = "DELETE from movies where ID = (?)"; 
    $sql = "DELETE from category where ID = (?)";    works fine.